# What is the fear of the unknown called?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, phobias

I am wondering what it's called when you fear the unknown, like I am scared of what's hidden deep in the ocean, far out in space, death, etc.--basically things I can't really explain. I just want to know what it's called.

Comment: I'm afraid to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Xenophobia

> The irrational sensation of fear experienced about a person or a
>   group of persons as well as situations that are perceived as strange
>   or foreign. It is the fear of anything that is beyond one’s comfort
>   zone.

[This article](http://www.fearof.net/fear-of-the-unknown-phobia-xenophobia/) would help explain a lot more on Xenophobia and also explains that this word would fit into your context.

Comment: This is probably closest, but I reckon (pace Rumsfeld) it refers to a fear of the 'known unknowns'.  I'm not sure that it describes that vague disquiet with no obvious cause that I think of when I hear *fear of the unknown*, and that I sense from the OP.

Comment: Yeah, I think that word is at least perceived, in common use, as meaning more a fear of the strange than a fear of that which is actually unknown.

Comment: @JHCL But the deep of the ocean is also while strange, not unknown. How could you fear something you don't even know it exists (or don't even believe it exists, before anybody brings up ghosts or similar).

Comment: @skymningen - The OP refers to "what's **hidden** deep in the ocean", not the deep ocean itself. The point is that *anything*, including the previously unimagined, might be present, and a threat.

Comment: I'm downvoting this, because while the "FearOf.net" article cited does define *xenophobia* as quoted in the answer, it is a non-standard definition, and none of the 5 dictionaries I checked, including OED, lists any definition even approaching it. The only dictionary-supported definition available is the standard, not-applicable-to-this-question "fear of foreigners [or strangers]".

Answer (score 0):

[Agoraphobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoraphobia)

> Agoraphobia is an anxiety disorder characterized by anxiety in situations where the sufferer perceives the environment to be dangerous, uncomfortable or unsafe. These situations can include wide-open spaces, uncontrollable social situations, unfamiliar places, shopping malls, airports and bridges.

And maybe [Panphobia](http://www.allaboutcounseling.com/library/panphobia/) or Fear of everything.

Answer (score 0):

Agnostophobia - Fear of the unknown.

Name of music album:
[http://www.amazon.com/Agnostophobia-Fear-Of-The-Unknown/dp/B006M6AZ6U](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006M6AZ6U).

Perhaps, the word is now copyrighted as name of the album, but the word while yet to be used with acceptable usage, is the most accurately descriptive.

Comment: Mr Brand in 1978 of Brooklyn Tech said he would get this word accepted looks like he got it done.